# Explanation : Simpler models beat BERT base

Tags: nlp, bert, text-classification

I have been trying to train different models for a multi-class classification task of texts. My data set consists of rows of text and its label. The texts are short sentences.
I tried the following models :
after generating embeddings using distilbert-base-uncased i trained :

- Random Forest Classifier :F1-Score: 0.59
- SVM :F1-Score: 0.63
- Gradient Boosting Classifier:F1-Score: 0.65
- MLPClassifier:F1-Score: 0.68

then :

- -BERT base :F1-Score: 0.40

Since BERT is supposed to be the most powerful model for this use case I was surprised with the result, I was trying to find an explanation and hypothesis for that. So has anyone faced similar results before . what do you think may be the reason?

Comment: I understand that you mean that you fine-tuned BERT. Can you show the training and validation curves and describe the hyperparameters used and other relevant stuff (learning rate, dataset size, optimizer, number of epochs, ...)?

Comment: I ask this because training on small data leads to overfitting. This was studied in the original BERT article, as well as in other articles, and there are techniques to palliate this problem, should this be the cause of your bad performance.